# SQL Server filter by date on a big table takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 300 million rows. One of the columns is type of `date` and when I select rows within two dates, it takes forever. About 3 minutes. The `date` field is indexed and I'm using SQL Server 2012 on a very powerful machine with high specs.

Is there anything I can do to make it significantly faster?

This is the query:

```
Select flightID, FlightDirection, DestinationID, FlightDuration
from T_Flights (nolock)
where FlightDate between @fromDate And @toDate
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221513/discussion-on-question-by-itay-b-sql-server-filter-by-date-on-a-big-table-takes).

Answer (score 1):

Scan is not good in the execution plan.
It should be seek.
try to add the columns in the select statement to the index and run the query.
If it still doesn't work another thing you could do is use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to see if it gives you any suggestions. Select the query in SSMS, right click and select Analyze Query in Database Engine Tuning Advisor.

Answer (score 0):

From your discussion, I understand that you are not having proper index on the date column. You have mentioned that index is being scanned. As you have not given enough details about which index being scanned, I would suggest you to create included index for suiting your query.

Now, your query can be satisfied by the below Nonclustered index itself. But, adding index brings additional overhead of maintaining it. So, add the index, only when your workload demanding it.

```sql
-- Assuming FlightID is primary key. primary key is included by default and no need 
--to add it separately. If FlightID is not primary key, add that to the list 
-- of included columns

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_FlightDate ON  dbo.T_Flights(FlightDate) 
INCLUDE (FlightDirection, DestinationID, FlightDuration)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have 300 million rows, then an index on `(flightdate)` *might* help -- but depending on how many flights per day and how many days.  You can include the other columns in the index which should help a bit more.

However, for what you want to do, it sounds like a better solution is to [*partition*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15) the table.  This would store each day's of data in a separate "file" and only the ones needed for the query would be read for a given query.

The downside is that this requires re-creating the table.  However, you might find that this is a big win performance-wise so worth the effort.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the Database Engine Tuning Advisor to optimize the query execution